# Send 2 array by ajax

Tags: javascript, arrays, codeigniter

First I want to create a simple array with data from `input`

And I want to do a loop and create an array with the line from the table.

some code here.

```
var first_array = {
  "warehouse": $("#warehouse").val(),
  "pricelist": $("#pricelist").val(),
  "date": $("#date").val(),
  "docstatus": "DR",
  "paymentterm": $("#paymentterm").val()
}

var second_array = []; //Thanks to sagar1025  help create the second array
$("#table_main tbody > tr").each(function() {
  var celdas = $(this).find('td');
  second_array.push({
    "line": $(celdas[0]).html(),
    "code": $(celdas[1]).html()
  });
});

/*Here my ajax*/

$.ajax({
  data: {
    array1: first_array,
    array2: second_array
  },
  url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>main/save_data",
  type: 'POST',
  async: false,
  cache: false,
  success: function(response) {

  },
  error: function() {
    toastr.error('ERROR', '', {
      progressBar: true,
      closeButton: true
    });
  }
});
```

Now I need to loop the second array in my `php` file
Here is how I declare one var from the first_array

```
$docstatus   = trim($this->input->post('array1[docstatus]', TRUE));
$array       = $this->input->post('array2[]', TRUE);
```

Im using `codeigniter`

Comment: you are mixing up arrays and objs.

Comment: @tyskr when is like this is an objs `{ }`?

Comment: reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer

Answer (score 1):

This is how you `push` or `add` multiple objects to an array

```
var second_array = [];
$("#table_main tbody > tr").each(function() {
    var celdas = $(this).find('td');
    second_array.push({
      "line": $(celdas[0]).html(),
      "code": $(celdas[1]).html()
    });
});
```

The Ajax call should be like something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    data: {
        array1: first_array,
        array2: second_array
    },
    url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>main/save_data",
    type: 'POST',
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    success: function(response) {

    },
    error: function() {
        toastr.error('ERROR', '', {
            progressBar: true,
            closeButton: true
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but how can loop through the data in my php file?

Comment: do you mean how to access the arrays in the PHP file? can you show some code from the PHP file?

Comment: I will edit my question but here how I declare an var from the first_array 
        `$docstatus   = trim($this->input->post('first_array[docstatus]', TRUE));` And I would like to loop the second_array and get the variables

Comment: when I try to do a foreach I have this error `Trying to get property 'line' of non-object`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing between [arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) and [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects), arrays are denoted with `[]` example `var array=[1,2,3,4]` objects are denoted with `{}` ex: var `Obj={color:"red"}`
you could send an object in your ajax call that contains both arrays or both objects depending on what you want so for instance you could do something like:

```
var globobj={}
    var first_object= {
      "warehouse": $("#warehouse").val(),
      "pricelist": $("#pricelist").val(),
      "date": $("#date").val(),
      "docstatus": "DR",
      "paymentterm": $("#paymentterm").val()
    } 
    var second_object= {
    "line": $(celdas[0]).html(),
    "code": $(celdas[1]).html()
    } 
    globobj.first_object=first_object
    globobj.second_object=second_object
```

so now that your objects are both combined you could use the `globobj`to make you ajax call